# Adding a div inside of an ActionLink

Tags: asp.net, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a tile that displays information but also needs to be a link. If the user clicks anywhere on the tile it needs to take them to the appropriate action.

Below is an image of what I have created.

[image]

The HTML

```
    <div class="tile">
        <div class="tile-text">Runs</div>
        <div class="tile-text details">Manage runs, routes, races, and goals</div>
        <div id="runs" class="tile-text live">You have a four mile run today</div>
    </div>
```

Now if I create an ActionLink, it will create the blue tile, but I am unsure of how to get the three child divs inside of the ActionLink.

I have tried the following ActionLink:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Runs", "Index", "Run", null, new { @class = "tile-text" })
```

This creates the following image:

[image]

So basically, how do I get the tile to link to the Action and still have all of the three child divs inside of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a `onclick="window.location.href='link'"` attribute on the `tile` `<div>`, and style it with `cursor: pointer` to make it look like a link, if needed.

Example:

```
<div class="tile" onclick="window.location.href='link'">
    <div class="tile-text">Runs</div>
    <div class="tile-text details">Manage runs, routes, races, and goals</div>
    <div id="runs" class="tile-text live">You have a four mile run today</div>
</div>
```

Or you could make the `tile` `<div>` be an `<a>` element and style it to be `display: block` and to include the appropriate `width` and `height`, then make all its children `<span>`s with `display: block`.

Example:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .tile, .tile-text { display: block; }
    // You could add width and height to .tile if needed.
    // Also, if you want to put tiles next to each other, inline-block for .tile
    // would be more appropriate.
</style>

<a class="tile" href="link">
    <span class="tile-text">Runs</span>
    <span class="tile-text details">Manage runs, routes, races, and goals</span>
    <span id="runs" class="tile-text live">You have a four mile run today</span>
</a>
```

Comment: Option 1 should work, but I don't like it because then it is not accessible to anybody not using Javascript. Option 2 ... is probably the better choice.

Comment: Option 1 involves minimal changes in the HTML, but indeed, it adds JavaScript to the mix. Option 2 works just as well, without any JavaScript involved, but there are some changes that need to be done in the HTML.

Comment: Check out my quick implementation of Radu's option 2.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the blue tile as an actual image. This clickable image should be placed in a div.

With CSS you can then put the image behind the text content using z-index / absolute positioning.

Comment: An image?! Just for a blue background?

Comment: There are *many* ways that don't involve an actual image... Take a look at my answer for just two ideas.

Comment: A little GIF file is much easier though.

Comment: An image is a lot less maintainable. If you need to change the color or the size, you need to use an image editor, to name just one disadvantage... Easier now is not always better in the long run. For example, when you write code, it's a lot easier to just copy / paste similar functionality everywhere, than to abstract the functionality, but in the long run, it will be infinitely harder to maintain.

Comment: True. Your option 2 is better. But as Radu said, the HTML needs to be reworked.

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick implementation of Radu's option 2.
All you need to do now is tidy it up and move the inline css into the css for your a class called title.

```
<body>  
<a class="tile" href="#" style="width: 200px; height: 300px; background-color: lightblue; display: block;">
    <h3 class="tile-text">Runs</h3>
    <p class="tile-text-details">Manage runs, routes, races, and goals</p>
    <p class="runs" class="tile-text-live">You have a four mile run today</p>
</a>
</body>
```

Comment: Having divs inside of an anchor tag isn't HTML compliant.